# Multiple PGFPlots in single figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to remake these plots from an article about Nested Containment List by Alekseyenko:

[image: Figure 5]

I have managed to do one plot:

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[
            title =         NestedContainmentList,
            width =         \textwidth,
            height =        5cm,
            xlabel =        {Query width (kb)},
            xtick =         {0.1, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100},
            xticklabels =   {0.1, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100},
            xtick pos =     left,
            ylabel =        {Speed ratio},
            ytick =         {1, 2, 4, 8, 16},
            yticklabels =   {1, 2, 4, 8, 16},
            ytick pos =     left,
            tick align =    outside, % Put ticks on the outside
        ]
            \addplot[mark=o] coordinates { (0.1,1) (0.5,1.1) (1,2) (5,4) (10,7) (50,12) (100,16)};
            \addplot[mark=*] coordinates { (0.1,3) (0.5,3.5) (1,5) (5,5.2) (10,8) (50,11) (100,15)};
        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Speed ratio for NestedContainmentList relative to other data structures.}
\end{figure}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{First Section}
\blindtext[3]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

However, I can't figure out how to properly introduce more plots and arrange them as in the article.

Comment: I don't have time to answer, but have a look at the `groupplots` library in pgfplots. It lets you arrange graphs and subgraphs very easily

Comment: Or use `subcaption` package to have (a), (b) ... so on

Comment: @darthbith Note how the x axis is different from (a), (c), (e) and (b), (d), (f). Is that possible to do easily with `groupplots`?

Comment: @lund.mikkel Yes, it should be pretty easy, simply setting options in the `nextgroupplot` command

Comment: @MikkelR.Lund, did the tip of darthbith help you to solve your problem?

Comment: @StefanPinnow Sorry, I actually don't remember. You'll have to try it out :)

Comment: @MikkelR.Lund, it would be nice, if **you** would test it and give us a response, because it was **your** question. Otherwise I will vote to close this question (in a few days) ...